# had been treated and being treated

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the difference between below two sentences and in which context we should use this.

> She had been treated with these medicines in 2004. 
>   She had being treated with these medicines in 2004.

One more example is

> She said as she had earlier being treated by the Guptas, in May 2003. 
>   She said as she had earlier been treated by the Guptas, in May 2003.

Please Explain

Answer (score 1):

> **She had been treated with these medicine in 2004** - (correct) It's in past participle tense. It means in the past the action occurred over a specified amount of time.
>
> **She had being treated with these medicine in 2004** - (Incorrect) We say "She is/was being treated...."

And as for your last two examples they are also incorrect. You need to omit "as"

> **She said she had earlier been treated by the Guptas, in May 2003** (correct)

Answer (score 0):

First, lets clear the confusion between *been* and *being*.

As a general rule, the word *been* will follow any form of *have* (i.e. has, had, will have). On the other hand, *being* is not used after *have or its forms*. The word *being* is used after *to be* and its forms such as *is, was, were*.

> She had been treated with these medicines in 2004 - means In the year of 2004, she was treated with those medicines. Using *had been* instead of *was* here would give a little connection to the present time (when this is spoken/written). One more thing, *had been* is a complete process. The thing has happened fully (I was in New York and I had been to New York -you completed the procedure of going and coming back). About this topic, read [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126599/have-been-had-been).
>
> She had being treated with these medicines in 2004 - does not sound grammatical. Something *being* means *one's self* and is not used in such context.

You say *Being a tall person* it's difficult for me to fit in a small car. Check that - *being* is referring to *self*. In this sense, if you want to tell that someone was treated, somebody's (self) was treated, you use *being* but then, it would take *is/was* as I wrote in the beginning. **She was being treated....**

Now the second example -

> She said as she had earlier been treated by the Guptas, in May 2003.

The sentence is in *passive* and thus, I'd recommend using *that*.

> She said *that* she had earlier been treated by the Guptas, in May 2003.

Good read [here](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_difference_between_BEEN_and_BEING?#slide=1) and [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15364/what-is-the-difference-between-being-and-having-been-in-this-context).